# Excel VBA Adding picture from HDD to my CenterHeader on my WorkSheets(1)

Tags: excel, vba, image, import, header

I have trouble making my VBA code work for the Center Header on the top of the page in Excel. I want it to load a picture (of my choosing) to the header.

It works for cell "C2", which my code currently works for, but I can't figure out how to get it to put the picture to the header instead of cell "C2".

My code is as follows (and it chooses the right picture I want to add by comparing the names and paths on the harddrive to an drop-down list. The script/code/macro is automaticly activated when I change type in the drop-down list):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myPict As Picture
Dim PictureLoc As String

If Target.Address = Range("A2").Address Then

ActiveSheet.Pictures.Delete

PictureLoc = "K:\MyPictures\" & Range("A2").Value & ".png"

With Range("C2")
    Set myPict = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PictureLoc)
    myPict.Top = .Top
    myPict.Left = .Left
    myPict.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
    myPict.ShapeRange.Width = 157
    myPict.ShapeRange.Height = 18
    myPict.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
End With

End If

End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Offtopic: As it is, the code is called everytime something in your worksheet is changed since you put the code inside the `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` event.

Comment: Hi L8n,
I'm not an expert in VBA, but it seems it isn't called everytime, but only when my target (A2) is changed. I have tried doing changes elsewhere in the sheet, and it isn't running the Private Sub (have made errors in the routine to check).
But appreciate the heads up :)

Comment: You're right, I totally missed the IF-clause in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the PageSetup object like this:

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .CentertHeaderPicture.Filename = PictureLoc
    .CenterHeader = "&G"
End With
```

Comment: Thanks alot!

Do you know of a way in VBA to make a drop-down menu with the images in my folder?

My code above refers to a cell "A2", where I want to choose a certain image for the header, where it checks the chosen filename against the files in the folder "K:\MyPictures\".

Do you have any suggestion how I could incorporate this into my code?

I have tried making a list with the help of "Name Manager" and INDEX command, but it won't read the location and I don't want to store the file in same folder as the images. (This method: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSCPVBWOqwc)

Answer (score 1):

To access the header of a worksheet (every worksheet is done seperate) use the `PageSetup` property of the worksheet object. [Official MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup)

There you can change the CenterHeaderPicture:

Example Code from [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.centerHeaderpicture)

```
Sub InsertPicture() 

 With ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CentertHeaderPicture 
 .FileName = "C:\Sample.jpg" 
 .Height = 275.25 
 .Width = 463.5 
 .Brightness = 0.36 
 .ColorType = msoPictureGrayscale 
 .Contrast = 0.39 
 .CropBottom = -14.4 
 .CropLeft = -28.8 
 .CropRight = -14.4 
 .CropTop = 21.6 
 End With 

 ' Enable the image to show up in the center header. 
 ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&G" 

End Sub
```